# mLAb : Temporary Failure in name resolution

Tags: python, mongodb, mlab

I'm not sure how this is happening in mLab or if it's something mLab should encounter. I left my python code processing all night inserting and updating document in mLab. Until I woke up this morning and found the error:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ds[....].mlab.com:[...] :[Errno:-3] 
Temporary Failure in Name Resolution
```

What does this mean and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you add the code snippet how you are updating the documents. This usually happens when Python code cannot resolve the domain name or DNS lookup issues.

- Two things I suggest would be to check how many of your records got inserted/updated in mongo lab.
- Code snippet which does this post request(Since mongo lab API actually does a POST of document that you actually insert/update. Check if it has a an option `allow_redirects=False` and set it.)

Comment: sorry I was unable to try this. I just shut down my computer and opened it again then it seemed to work fine now. I do want to know why.

Comment: I really don't thing you will get this quite often since this happens usually due to DNS resolution issues.